# When I click on social media icon, the logo in the icon shifts up

Tags: html, css

I am having an issue with my social media buttons where for some strange reason when I click on it, the inner text slides up.

[image]

when I click on this icon, the 'f' within the circle moves up a few pixels. Only happens on the click. When I release it goes by to the center.

```
<div class="social-buttons">  
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://test.com/foundation-level-it-professional-certification/" target="blank" class="social-margin" rel="noopener noreferrer"> 
<div class="social-icon facebook">
<i class="fa fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</div>
</a>


.social-buttons{
 display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* flex vertical alignment */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.social-icon {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
   box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 138px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 138px;
  border-radius: 138px;
  border: 5px solid;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1px;
  padding-top: 11px;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.social-icon-no-border {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
     box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-border-radius: 138px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 138px;
  border-radius: 138px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: all 0.5s;
}

.social-icon:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
  }

.social-icon-no-border:hover{
        transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
}
```

Comment: the scale seems to be off center. does it still happen when you delete the scale command?

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is what you want.

```css
.social-buttons{
 display: flex;
  align-items: center; /* flex vertical alignment */
  justify-content: space-evenly;
}

.social-icon {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 50%;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid blue;
  display:inline-flex;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  font-size:50px;
  
  transition: all 0.5s;
}


.social-icon:hover {
    transform: rotate(360deg)scale(1.3);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/js/all.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.1/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="social-buttons">  

<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=https://test.com/foundation-level-it-professional-certification/" target="blank" class="social-margin" rel="noopener noreferrer"> 
<div class="social-icon facebook">

<i class="fab fa-facebook" aria-hidden="true"></i> 
</div>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

After much trial an error, the culprit was the border. Once I commented out  `border: 5px solid;`, then it fixed the issue.